# Number Theory - Method of Proof explanation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, parity

So I came across a proof:

(i) $2^n$ is the sum of two consecutive integers.

**Proof:**

The relation $(2k - 1) + (2k + 1) = 2^n$ implies $k = 2^{n-2}$ and we obtain $2^n = (2^{n-1} - 1) + (2^{n-1} + 1)$.

**My question:**

Why is the assumption $(2k - 1) + (2k + 1) = 2^n$ to deduce that $k = 2^{n-2}$ valid? Aren't we trying to prove that  $(2k - 1) + (2k + 1) = 2^n$?

Comment: Don't you mean two consecutive odd integers?

Comment: More importantly: Why are $2k-1$ and $2k+1$ considered consecutive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof as presented has several problems. Personally, I'd prefer something like this:

**Claim.** If $n\ge 2$, then $2^n$ is the sum of two consecutive odd integers.

*Proof.* As $n\ge 2$, it follows that $k=2^{n-2}$ is an integer, and then $2k-1$ and $2k+1$ are consecutive odd integers. As $(2k-1)+(2k+1)=4k=2^n, $
the claim follows. $\square$

The formulation "implies $k=2^{n-2}$" goes the wrong way and belongs rather to a research attempt to *find* a proof.

Answer (score 0):

$(2k-1) + (2k+1) = 4k = 2^n \to k = 2^n/2^2 = 2^{n-2}.$